# What the difference between my code "++count" and "count++" in the "Kth Smallest Element in a BST" solution?

Tags: java, algorithm

In the algorithm problem "Find the Kth Smallest Element in a BST"
(https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst), my solution is below:

```
 public class Solution {
        private int count;
        public int kthSmallest(TreeNode root, int k) {
        if (root == null)
            return 0;
        int kth = kthSmallest(root.left, k);
        if (count == k)
            return kth;

        /********** section A *************/
        else if (++count == k)
            return root.val;
        /********** section A end *********/

        /********** section B *************/
        /*
        else if (count == k - 1) 
            return root.val;
        count++;
        */
        /********** section B end *********/

        /********** section C *************/
        /*
        else if (count == k - 1) {
            count++;
            return root.val;
        }
        */
        /********** section C end *********/
        return kthSmallest(root.right, k);
    }
}
```

In the leetcode online judge, section A is right and section B is wrong, which I think are equal to each other, I could not figure out the difference between the two sections.

P.S.  Added the section C.

- In section A

  count increase no matter `++count == k` is true of false.
- In section B

  count only increases when `count == k - 1` is false, because when the `count == k - 1` is true, the function will return and no longer execute any more. But **Since we have got the right value returned, is it necessary to increase the value of count?**
- In section C

  count updated only when `count == k - 1`
- Conclusion
  Section B is not equal to A, neither section C, when I integrated section B with section C, as showed below:

  ```
      else if (count == k - 1) {
          count++;
          return root.val;
      }
      count++;
  ```

it is equal to section A and passed the online judge, which is not elegant as section A.

:)

Comment: While using section B, your code wont compile, because you will have a dangling `else` statement below. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Section `B` would be same as section `A` if you would move `count++;` line before return statement.

Comment: @Codebender Yeah, there is a little bug, and I have fixed it, which will not affect my point.

Comment: @Pshemo  I have fixed the bug and the count in section B will increment no matter "count == k - 1" is true or false. But the solution on the online judge is still wrong with section B.

Answer (score 3):

The value of the private instance variable `count` is updated in Section A regardless of whether the comparison succeeds or not.

That is, at the point of comparison occurring at the start of the section:

In Section A, if `count == k - 1` holds true, the private `count` variable is incremented by 1 before `root.val` is returned.

In Section B, if `count == k - 1` holds true, the `count` variable is not modified, and `root.val` is returned.

Comment: if count == k - 1 is true in section B, which means we get the returned value, the function is ended, why we need update the count?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, in section A `count` gets incremented anyway, even if it does not equal `k`.
In section B it gets incremented only if `count` **DOES NOT** equal `k-1`.

That's because when using `++i`, the variable gets incremented first, then used (assigned, compared, etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
    int count=3;
   int k=5;
 if (++count == k)
      System.out.println("A"+ count);

  else if (count == k - 1) 
       System.out.println("B"+ count);

 System.out.println("C"+ count);
```

i write similar code

output;
B4
C4

after first if case, count is anyway **count =4**

then k will be 4

finally second if case will work

```
int count=3;
   int k=5;
 if (count++ == k)
      System.out.println("A"+ count);

  else if (count == k - 1) 
       System.out.println("B"+ count);

 System.out.println("C"+ count);
```

output:
B4 C4

but if int count=4(for second code block )

output:
C5